# How to use BeginInvoke method correctly?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have got this code. It works but it freezes the UI.
What I want to know is how to use WPF BeginInvok method corectly?

```
private void ValidateAuthURL_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Button)sender).Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, 
        new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            bool result = false;
            try
            {
```

Comment: From the example you've posted, you're using it right. However what code is called within the Lambda function? It is possible you have re-entrancy and/or a deadlock - are you using other threads? What is the CPU usage like when frozen. Maximum or zero?

Comment: @Dr. Andrew Burnett-Thompson    I just use  var request = WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl) as HttpWebRequest; and etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your delegate is going to be executed *in the UI thread*. That's what `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` is there for. I assume you *really* want to execute that delegate in a background thread... then you should use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to get *back* to the UI thread in order to update the UI later.

In terms of getting to a background thread, you could:

- Use the thread pool directly (`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`)
- Use `BackgroundWorker`
- Start a new thread
- Use `Task.Factory.StartNew` (if you're using .NET 4)